# How to organize Bacula config files for about 100 servers

Tags: linux, backup, configuration, bacula

I'm testing bacula and I'm going to make of it my central backup & restore system. I'm testing configuration, backuping & restoring remote host and etc. The configuration is one file and when I put there 100 clients definitions, jobs, file sets this file will be unreadeable. Bacula has ability to include configurations files. My goal is to make the nice readable and easy to fing config files.

My plan was to make catalog conf.d in /etc/bacula and there make config files for filesets (all sets in one file), configurations of clients and jobs for clients in one file per client, storage in another file, global configuration of monitor and bacula-dir in /etc/bacula/bacula-dir.conf

I have bacula-dir and bacula-sd on different servers (bacula-dir in lan, sd in DMZ with most off all file deamons (clients), and sd has two storage devices).

I want to make things right from the beginning, so my question is what is your best way/experience to organize bacula configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ours is done this way, it's pretty manageable. I will say though that I'm not our Bacula guru.

```
root@backup:/etc/bacula# tree
.
├── bacula-dir.conf
├── bacula-fd.conf
├── bacula.pem
├── bacula-sd.conf
├── bconsole.conf
├── common_default_passwords
├── conf.d
│   ├── clients.conf
│   ├── filesets.conf
│   ├── jobdefs.conf
│   ├── jobs.conf
│   ├── pools.conf
│   ├── schedule.conf
│   └── storage.conf
├── encryption
│   ├── fd-company.cert
│   ├── fd-company.key
│   ├── fd-company.pem
│   ├── fd-example.pem
│   ├── master.cert
│   └── master.key
└── scripts
    ├── btraceback.gdb
    ├── delete_catalog_backup
    ├── disk-changer
    ├── dvd-handler
    ├── make_catalog_backup
    ├── make_catalog_backup_awk
    ├── make_catalog_backup.pl
    ├── mtx-changer
    ├── mtx-changer.conf
    └── query.sql
```

Comment: I was thinking about something very similar :)